# check how long the person has not used the application flutter

Tags: flutter, background

I'm looking to make a feature that prompts the user to open the App to use for a learning app:
If the user does not open the app after 2 days to learn, remind the user to open the app(push notification). And I am not sure how to check how long the person has not used the application.
What should I learn to do such a feature

Comment: One way I suggest is basically whenever app is opened note the time of request made to server and later you can use it on server side to send notification.

Comment: If you are running on iOS it’s not possible to do it from within the app that is in the background. You have to use Push Notifications. But you didn’t specify the platform…

Comment: I found a way: catch the onpause, on resume, inactive application lifecycle events to check the user action field. if onpause or inactive, the default push notification will run for the next 2 days, if in 2 days the user enters the app (active, onResume), the push notification will be canceled.